# Can't Install Laravel 5 or Run Any Laravel Project After Three Weeks of Trying

Tags: php

I'm in my third week of trying to install any Laravel project, with laravel5-example being the latest one. I'm using Windows 7. I've tried via XAMPP, I've installed composer, Virtual-box and Vagrant.

One tutorial had me installing Node.js. I've tried to install Homestead to no avail. Everything, at some point, results in errors which are never mentioned in the tutorials.

I've downloaded about ten projects in the hopes of learning something about Laravel, with zero luck. It seems that everyone has a different method and everyone leaves out crucial steps, or gives an instruction like "`launch it`" but doesn't instruct how to do that.

I've tried installing in

> C:\xampp
>   C:\xampp\htdocs
>   C:\users{username}\AppData\Roaming
>   C:\ 
>   and others.

I've watched countless video tutorials, read countless StackOverflow threads, and in 21 days I've achieved nothing. Not even close to just seeing a project run on my machine.

I haven't been this disgusted since Windows 8 was released! Can anyone point me to something that really is for a beginner? I thought I'd be learning Laravel by now and after attempting for several hours per day for three weeks, I haven't gotten past installing whatever Laravel needs to even run.

Thank you

Comment: r u following this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2

Comment: try this http://tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-windows-xampp/  check all the requirement is there. check version

Comment: @m2j Thank you. That's one I haven't seen. I'll take a look.

Comment: @m2j  Yes, I'm following the Laravel docs, but they give a lot of general instructions to install one thing or another, and I hit dead ends because even those things have incomplete instructions or conflict with the instructions on the Laravel site.

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/1

Comment: So, what happened when you installed Composer and did `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` as directed in their quickstart?

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think I've seen Quickstart before. All I saw was "Installation" at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2. Thank you for pointing that out. I do think I ran that Composer command but I've lost track of what error resulted from what action. Maybe I should clarify, I think Laravel is installed, but it's getting existing projects to run that I have been unable to do. Some say you should do a new install per project, they often refer to folders or files without specifying where they can be found. I searched for usr/bin for hours before I saw a comment that that was only on a Unix system.

Comment: @RightThisWay If you have a Laravel project, go into its directory and do `php artisan serve`. Simplest way to run it for basic testing.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you!! At least I run these projects. Wow! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to have any troubles with installation, try to use Homestead which is independent from your OS. All you need is install VMWare and Vagrant like any other Windows software. Then install Homestead using these instructions:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead

In that case, you will not need cofiguring and running any Windows servers like XAMPP.

Also, try to turn off a firewall while you're installing Homestead and Laravel, because newbies have a lot of problems caused by firewall.

Try installing Homestead and if you'll meet any troubles, come back here and we'll help you to fix them.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. I did finally try Homestead but that just added to confusion. In some places, there are instructions as to what directory you should be in when entering a command. In others, there isn't. Laravel site says, "You may install Homestead by simply cloning the repository." Cool! What repository? Where is it? How do I clone it? "Consider cloning the repository into a Homestead folder within your 'home' directory." OK. What "home" directory? I see a "laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead" directory. Is that "home?" Is that dir name even correct?

Comment: I've been following various instructions for all these different things, doing operations or saving things in specific directories - I don't even know where everything is now. Started with XAMPP/htdocs, then Users/UserName, I tried C:\ (root), I have no idea what is right. One error was, "default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly." Well that isn't good. So what on earth is a "guest addition?" No clue.

Comment: Thank you again very much for your help. What is different about the "ready made" box? By "cloning," do they mean just making a copy of a directory, or "cloning" as in git or something? Where is the "home" directory or the "Homestead folder?" I'm not even sure where it's installed, so for all I know the directory with the word "homestead" isn't what they're talking about.

Comment: Home directory is any directory where you want keep all work stuff, for example, you can create D:\MyWork\ directory and run all commands there. The simpliest way to do that for guy who likes GUI (I like GUI myself) is to use FreeCommander, go to the home (MyWork) directory and press Ctrl+D. Then you can just run git command. After that you will have Homestead directory inside MyWork directory and all Laravel projects will be in the same MyWork directory.

Comment: By cloning they mean that GIT will clone everthing from repository. This simply means GIT will just automatically download all the stuff from GitHub and put it into Homestead directory on your computer. That's cloning. All you need to do is to run git command and wait.

Comment: OK, that explanation of the directory hierarchy is helpful. That's the kind of thing I couldn't find info on. I feel like I should delete everything from the past few weeks and start over. Should I just work with my web server directly? Doesn't that cut out some of these requirements? I have no idea how all this stuff has affected my local PC's security. Virtual Machines, open ports, MySQL databases. All this has to be run every time you work on a project, right? Just to view it on a local PC? Is that correct? You've given me a *little* bit of hope so I'll get back to work now. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Vagrant is virtual box, which means you have like mini-linux-computer inside your OS (with it's own MySQL, Web server and stuff). That means it will not affect security of your computer. But, since you're having so much trouble installing Laravel, I'd recommend you to turn off firewall, because composer and git have to have access to the Web to download stuff. That's a hole in secutiry. Just turn back on firewall (or setup it correcly) after you'll finish setting up Homestead and Laravel.

Comment: I'm stuck again. StackOverflow says not to have extended comments, asks if I want to move it to chat. How do I know? I just wanted one place that has *all* the right directions. Anyway, firewall is off but now I read that bash init.sh, which Laravel says to run, is strictly for Unix. Wonderful. There is a init.bat that seems to be what I need to run but yet again, people like me get stuck there. How to run as admin? I've seen ten suggestions so far. None worked. This is the "easy" way to install LOL? I'm throwing in the towel. So much for frameworks. **Thank you** for your help.

Comment: I agree it's not easy, but you should learn all this stuff if you want have a deal with modern frameworks. I can't afford take it to the chat, because it's too time consuming, I'm really sorry. Yes, you should just run init.bat and it will do the same things. To run as administrator, look for cmd.exe (it's window's command line tool, look in C:\Windows\System32), right click and choose 'Run as administrator'.